# ADB Keeps Crashing

Tags: android, adb, flutter

I am new to flutter and trying to run a newly created flutter app that is untouched. From over 1 week of troubleshooting, it seems flutter may not be running due to adb issues so I tried to run some of the adb commands manually which I now realize crashes when certain commands are run from the command line.

For example, the following command crashes adb and partially lists the properties up to '[wlan.wfd.status]: [disconnected]':

```
adb shell getprop
```

[image]

OS: Windows 10 Enterprise 64 Bit

I also tried this using another windows 10 machine running same version and had the same issue.

ADB Version:

```
adb --version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.40
Version 4797878
```

When I do the same via Windows 7, there is no issue and the commands run successfully and list all properties. I am also able to run the new flutter app on windows 7 without issue

See flutter output on Windows 10 that shows an error but doesnt show the adb crash in the screenshot above.

```
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel dev, v0.5.7, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393], locale en-US)
|Error retrieving device properties for ro.product.cpu.abi:

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[√] VS Code, 32-bit edition (version 1.24.1)
[√] Connected devices (1 available)


$ flutter run
Error retrieving device properties for ro.product.cpu.abi:

Launching lib/main.dart on SM G930F in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Unexpected failure from adb: Invalid argument(s): The source must not be null
Error launching application on SM G930F.
```

Any help identifying the cause of the adb crash would be appreciated as I think if this is fixed, then flutter will work.

Comment: Try running _any_ adb command that interacts with your phone in the command line and see if the crash occurs every time. In my case, as soon as a session is closed, it chrashes, always, no matter what it is I asked it to do. Also: version 1.0.36 and lower don't crash here. There's another user on Stack Overflow who has reported fixing the crashes by that downgrade. However, for me, the version is too old :(

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue before as it gets a lot of attention in [this GitHub post](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33938). For a temporary fix, you can follow [this thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33938#issuecomment-499250288):

> I found a temporary fix while we wait for a solution provided by the
> Flutter team
>
> - Windows: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.2-windows.zip
> - macOS: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.2-darwin.zip
> - Linux: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.2-linux.zip
>
> this download contains the platform tools for 28.0.1

This was then resolved in the [following releases of SDK Platform-Tools](SDK Platform-Tools).

> 29.0.1 (June 2019)
>
> - adb
>
>   - Hotfix for Windows crashes (https://issuetracker.google.com/134613180)

For current users, try to use the [latest SDK Platform-Tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools#revisions). As most of the known bugs in the previous releases were resolved.